# Intuit PaymentNetwork metadata for invoice payment page

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

QuickBooks Online offers the option to enable payments for invoice using the Intuit PaymentNetwork. Having signed up for Intuit PaymentNetwork, the option appears on the QBO invoice edit page. If checked, emailed invoices will include a secret URL taking the customer to [a page where they can pay the invoice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYoXL.jpg).

Is it possible to reconstruct this URL from information provided through the IPP DataServices API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this URL is not available through the IDS API's.